# Converting/Cast to SuperType Variance

Tags: c#, interface, covariance, contravariance

I have the following:

```
public class MyExample : IMyExample
{
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;
}

public class MySubType : IMySubType, MyExample
{
    public List<Stuff> ExtraProperty {get; set;}
}

public IMyExample ReturnMyExample()
{
    return new MyExample();
}

public class Stuff
{
 public string StuffDescription{get; set;}
public int StuffCounter {get; set;}
}
```

I want to:

```
IMySubType MagicType = ReturnMyExample();
```

I believe this could be solved with variance, but am having trouble gelling it all in.

Yes, I know that under normal circumstances this is not possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Variance is to do with generics, and the only use of generics you've got here is with `List<T>` (which is invariant anyway). I assume `public string MySubType` should be `public class MySubType`? Please edit if so. But no, you can't cast an object to a type that it isn't. (What would the value of `ExtraProperty` be? That field isn't present in `MyExample`, which is what you've created an instance of.)